# Posterior with a much larger uncertainty than the prior

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior

I have done an MCMC analysis with many variables. One of my nuisance parameters has a Normal prior distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. The posterior distribution for this parameter has mean 0 and standard deviation 10. Is there any conflict here? I would think this is an ordinary possible outcome but I have doubts from people who are looking at my results.

Comment: In this way the question is impossible to answer. It can be a model which is not well done or it can be normal. Anyway i think there is a need of more information to answer properly.

Comment: It all depends on the likelihood. In a Normal-Normal case, this would be impossible but for non-Normal likelihoods, that the variance increases is a possibility.

Comment: @Xi'an Can this occur with a Normal likelihood but a mixture of Normal and Uniform priors?