# general rules of the variance of the posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, variance, posterior

In Bayesian posterior inference, we have the following equation relating posterior to prior and likelihood:

$$\pi(\theta|D)\propto \pi(\theta)l(D|\theta).$$

Is there any general rules that quantify the variance of the posterior vs the variance of the prior and variance of likelihood? Of course, without knowing the specific forms of the prior and likelihood, it is impossible to have any exact relations. But I am wondering if some approximate heuristics could be derived, potentially with some assumptions. In particular, if $\pi(\theta)$ is Gaussian and $D$ is also Gaussian around $\theta$, then $\pi(\theta|D)$ is also Gaussian and we can work out its variance. But is such an assumption reasonable? Or are there better estimates?

Having some estimate could be helpful, for example, to determine the approximate number of data points to acquire if a specific uncertainty level of the posterior is desired.

Answer (score 3):

##### A simple "rule of thumb" can be derived from the conjugate normal model

As you correcly point out, the simplest way to examine this is to consider an archetypal model form like the normal model to derive an appropriate "rule of thumb".  To this end, let's consider the Bayesian normal model using the conjugate prior for the mean parameter $\mu$ and with a fixed precision parameter $\lambda$.  ([Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)) is the inverse of the variance if you haven't seen this before.)  This model can be written formally as:

$$\begin{align}
X_1,...,X_N | \mu, \lambda &\sim \text{IID N} \Big( \mu, \frac{1}{\lambda} \Big), \\[10pt]
\mu | \lambda &\sim \text{N} \Big( \mu_0, \frac{1}{\tau_0} \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Under this model the posterior distribution for $\mu$ (conditional on $\lambda$) is:

$$p(\mu|\mathbf{x}, \lambda)
= \text{N} \Big( \mu_n, \frac{1}{\tau_n} \Big),$$

with posterior mean and precision given respectively by:

$$\mu_n = \frac{\tau_0 \mu_0 + n \lambda \bar{y}_n}{\tau_0 + n \lambda}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\tau_n = \tau_0 + n \lambda.$$

Now, since our interest is in the prior-to-posterior change in variance, we are only interested in the latter equation for the precision parameter.  As you can see from that equation, there is a simple rule for updating the precision: the posterior precision of the mean parameter is the prior precision plus $n$ lots of the sampling precision.  (You can easily get the corresponding rule for the prior-to-posterior variance, but it is not as simple.)  This means that ---within the normal model--- the posterior precision is always higher than the prior precision and so the corresponding posterior variance is always lower than the prior variance.

This gives you a "rule of thumb" that holds exactly in the normal model but would only be an approximation (at best) in other models.  It is not always the case that the posterior variance is lower than the prior variance, so be careful with how widely you consider this "rule" to apply.  It will tend to apply reasonably well in cases where the sampling distribution and prior distribution are both unimodal and close to the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

> Having some estimate could be helpful, for example, to determine the approximate number of data points to acquire if a specific uncertainty level of the posterior is desired.

This is actually pretty related to the field of "active learning". One key theorem that bounds a "variance" like term is given by Chernoff-Hofdinger bound which states in a simplified form that if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid. random variables then
$$ P(|\overline{X} - E[\overline{X}]| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\left(-2nt^2 \right)$$
So the probability that your empirically estimated mean deviates from the true mean drops exponentially with the number of datapoints $n$ you consider. If you now want to compute the number of data points such that the probability $\delta$ of deviating from $\overline{X}$ at most by $t$. Then you can compute a lower bound by
$$ \delta \leq 2\exp\left(-2nt^2 \right) \iff n \leq \frac{\log(\frac{\delta}{2})}{-2t^2}$$
This would hold for arbitrary distributions; however; thus the bound is often too loose.

> In particular, if π(θ) is Gaussian and D is also Gaussian around θ, then π(θ|D) is also Gaussian and we can work out its variance.

In this case, you consider a jointly Gaussian model of the data. This will perfectly work if your data is Gaussian-like distributed, much better than some general bounds. However if the data is not Gaussian-like your generative model is wrong, thus the posterior will most likely not concentrate around the true value of your parameter.

This approach is also much more general. If $\pi(\theta)$ is the conjugate prior to the likelihood $l(D|\theta)$ and if this prior has a closed-form expression for the variance, then you can also compute the posterior variance in closed form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't clearly see how the Chernoff bound relates to my question. It's a general bound on the variance of random variables, but how does it relate to that of the variance of the prior and likelihood, particularly in the non-conjugate case? For example, if either the prior or likelihood variance is high, then the posterior variance is also high, but I'm wondering if there's something more to say about it.